# Equations one below the other

Tags: equations

how can I get two equations one below the other, listed on the right side

```
\begin{equation}
LCS(X_{n},Y_{m-1})\\      enumerate
LCS(X_{n-1},Y_{m})
\end{equation}
```

I try with this:

```
\begin{align}
LCS(X_{n},Y_{m-1})\\
LCS(X_{n-1},Y_{m})
\end{align}
```

but 
I do not want to have two enumerates, I just want a enumerate for both

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you please clarify the following points : 
- what do you mean by *listed on the right side*, you mean the numbering ?
- *enumerates* refers to a specific environment in `LaTeX`, are you also refering to the equation numbering ?

Comment: @BambOo yes 
I refer to the numeration 
with listed and enumerate

Comment: Given my current understanding of your issue, replace `align` by  a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to propose you multiple options

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
LCS(X_{n},Y_{m-1})\\
LCS(X_{n-1},Y_{m})\nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
LCS(X_{n},Y_{m-1})\\
LCS(X_{n-1},Y_{m})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
LCS(X_{n},Y_{m-1})\\
LCS(X_{n-1},Y_{m})
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: for 'split' should use the package empheq?

Comment: Nope, just `amsmath`